# Function pointer only works inside main?

Tags: c++, function, binary-search-tree, function-pointers, traversal

Code below shows a simple insert into a binary search tree (hand written NOT STL) i have used function pointers in my bst and would like to traverse the tree from outside of main. how do i get it to work outside of main?

i get an error at tree.inorder() saying no instance of overloaded function

handler class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printTree(int & a)
{
    cout << a << endl;
}

handler::handler()
{

}


void handler::printTree()
{   

    BinarySearchTree<int> tree;

    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(5);
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(20);

    tree.inorder(printTree);
}
```

main class

```
#include <iostream>

#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
#include "handler.h"


int main()
{
    handler handle; 

    handle.printTree();
}
```

```
template<class T>
inline void BinarySearchTree<T>::inorder(Node * root, void(*inorderPtr)(T &)) const
{
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        if (root->left != nullptr)
        {
            inorder(root->left, inorderPtr);
        }
        inorderPtr(root->data);
        if (root->right != nullptr)
        {
            inorder(root->right, inorderPtr);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No data" << endl;
    }
}

template<class T>
inline void BinarySearchTree<T>::inorder(void(*inorderPtr)(T &)) const
{
    inorder(this->root, inorderPtr);
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that `tree.inorder(printTree);` is the same as `tree.inorder(this->printTree);`?

Comment: please include the exact error message in the question

Comment: i do not, i know it is probably simple, i wouldnt of asked for help D:

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0304 no instance of overloaded function "BinarySearchTree<T>::inorder [with T=int]" matches the argument list

Comment: @Chronial i am unsure what u meant by that please explain

Comment: @Getwrong you have two functions named `printTree`. Try giving one a different name.

Comment: @Chronial im so very disappointed in myself right now

Answer (score 2):

`BinarySearchTree<T>::inorder` is declared `const` hence `root->data` is `const` and you cannot call `inorderPtr(root->data);` because `inorderPtr` (aka `printTree(int&)`) expects a non-const `int&`.

Fix it by fixing const-correctness. You could have two `BinarySearchTree<T>::inorder`. One `const` taking a `void(*inorderPtr)(const T &)` and the other non-const, taking a `void(*inorderPtr)(T &)`.

Comment: will give this a go